# CSS submenu 2nd level issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on this site https://webdev08.amontagnana.it/ .
Someone else did the work a couple years ago and I'm just adding some new features.
The person that worked on this site used CSS to make the menù elements' background black ( #3c3c3c ) when you hover it or to indicate the path when you are in a specific page.
That works also for the submenu.

The issue that i'm finding is that, if I'm on a submenù with more than 1 level, the whole submenu's background gets black, not only the one that i'm in.

I'm kinda new to this stuff and i'm not a CSS expert, tbh.

I uploaded here the whole CSS style https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSOi7kRFKEHW2DsNbUItI8t1Dg5lH8ftO9d3m6h2ZlzcIe6kCWaO74SfKJK-08PJfiyB82p5o78Tze4/pub

It's the first time I have to share so many lines of code and drive is the first thing that came to my mind. If there is something more suitable, i'm sorry but I didn't know it

Comment: PSA: you can use `github.com` to share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code **i.e.** [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.